ICE connection stuck in FAILED state
The ICE connection is stuck in FAILED state despite using both STUN and TURN servers in WebRTC.
Some context on -

I am behind a commercial WiFi-router.Using golang.
Both offerrer and acceptor are running on my local machine on different ports.
The signalling server is running on the same machine.
I am able to telnet my TURN servers. So, they are reachable.
I have tried connecting over both TCP and UDP.

I have attached my code below.
Appreciate the help!
offerrer.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    webrtc "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3"
)

func getSDP(signalServerURL, name string) string {
    signalServerURL += "/signal/" + name
    resp, err := http.Get(signalServerURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(respBody)
}

func setSDP(signalServerURL, name string, offerJson []byte) error {
    signalServerURL += "/signal"
    data := map[string]string{
        "name": name,
        "sdp":  string(offerJson),
    }
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error marshalling data: %v", err)
    }
    _, err = http.Post(signalServerURL, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    return err
}

func main() {
    signalServerURL := "http://127.0.0.1:9099"

    /*
            {
                urls: "turn:global.relay.metered.ca:80",
                username: "bd1ed97e211e0e351fad721b",
                credential: "rsot1XO4eSJXISCG",
              },
              {
                urls: "turn:global.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp",
                username: "bd1ed97e211e0e351fad721b",
                credential: "rsot1XO4eSJXISCG",
              },
              {
                urls: "turn:global.relay.metered.ca:443",
                username: "bd1ed97e211e0e351fad721b",
                credential: "rsot1XO4eSJXISCG",
              },
              {
                urls: "turns:global.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp",
                username: "bd1ed97e211e0e351fad721b",
                credential: "rsot1XO4eSJXISCG",
              }
    */
    peerConnection, err := webrtc.NewPeerConnection(webrtc.Configuration{
        ICEServers: []webrtc.ICEServer{
            {
                URLs:       []string{"turn:global.relay.metered.ca:80?transport=tcp"},
                Username:   "bd1ed97e211e0e351fad721b",
                Credential: "rsot1XO4eSJXISCG",
            },
            {
                URLs:       []string{"turn:global.relay.metered.ca:443?transport=tcp"},
                Username:   "bd1ed97e211e0e351fad721b",
                Credential: "rsot1XO4eSJXISCG",
            },
        },
        ICETransportPolicy: webrtc.ICETransportPolicyRelay,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dataChannel, err := peerConnection.CreateDataChannel("data", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create data channel:", err)
    }

    peerConnection.OnICEGatheringStateChange(func(state webrtc.ICEGathererState) {
        fmt.Printf("Offerer ICE Gathering State: %s\n", state.String())
    })

    peerConnection.OnICEConnectionStateChange(func(state webrtc.ICEConnectionState) {
        fmt.Printf("Offerer ICE Connection State: %s\n", state.String())
    })

    peerConnection.OnICECandidate(func(candidate *webrtc.ICECandidate) {
        if candidate != nil {
            fmt.Printf("ICE Candidate gathered: %s\n", candidate.ToJSON().Candidate)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("ICE Candidate gathering complete.")
        }
    })

    dataChannel.OnOpen(func() {
        fmt.Println("Data channel is open, sending message...")
        err := dataChannel.SendText("Hello from offerer")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error sending text message:", err)
        }

        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        for {
            fmt.Println("Enter text (or type 'exit' to quit): ")
            input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
            input = strings.TrimSpace(input)

            // Check if the user wants to exit
            if input == "exit" {
                fmt.Println("Exiting...")
                break
            }

            err := dataChannel.SendText(input)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }

    })

    fmt.Println("running offerer...")

    offer, err := peerConnection.CreateOffer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(offer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    offerJSON, _ := json.Marshal(offer)

    gatheringComplete := webrtc.GatheringCompletePromise(peerConnection)
    <-gatheringComplete

    fmt.Println("pushing local sdp...")
    err = setSDP(signalServerURL, "person1", offerJSON)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("local sdp signalled...")

    retry := 0
    var sdp string
    for {
        retry += 1
        if retry >= 10 {
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(retry) * time.Second)
        sdp = getSDP(signalServerURL, "person2")

        notFound := "No sdp info exists for name"
        if !strings.Contains(sdp, notFound) {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("remote sdp received...")
    fmt.Println(sdp)

    var remoteSDP webrtc.SessionDescription
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(sdp), &remoteSDP)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(remoteSDP)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        dataChannel.OnMessage(func(msg webrtc.DataChannelMessage) {
            fmt.Printf("Message from answerer: %s\n", string(msg.Data))
        })
    }()

    select {}
}


acceptor.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    webrtc "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3"
)

func getSDP(signalServerURL, name string) string {
    signalServerURL += "/signal/" + name
    resp, err := http.Get(signalServerURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(respBody)
}

func setSDP(signalServerURL, name string, offerJson []byte) error {
    signalServerURL += "/signal"
    data := map[string]string{
        "name": name,
        "sdp":  string(offerJson),
    }
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error marshalling data: %v", err)
    }
    _, err = http.Post(signalServerURL, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    return err
}

func main() {
    signalServerURL := "http://127.0.0.1:9099"

    peerConnection, err := webrtc.NewPeerConnection(webrtc.Configuration{
        ICEServers: []webrtc.ICEServer{
            {
                URLs: []string{"stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"},
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    retry := 0
    var sdp string

    fmt.Println("running acceptor...")

    for {
        retry += 1
        if retry >= 20 {
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(retry) * time.Second)
        sdp = getSDP(signalServerURL, "person1")

        notFound := "No sdp info exists for name"
        if !strings.Contains(sdp, notFound) {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("remote sdp received...")
    println(sdp)

    var remoteSDPOffer webrtc.SessionDescription
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(sdp), &remoteSDPOffer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(remoteSDPOffer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    answer, err := peerConnection.CreateAnswer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    peerConnection.OnICEGatheringStateChange(func(state webrtc.ICEGathererState) {
        fmt.Printf("Answerer ICE Gathering State: %s\n", state.String())
    })

    peerConnection.OnICEConnectionStateChange(func(state webrtc.ICEConnectionState) {
        fmt.Printf("Answerer ICE Connection State: %s\n", state.String())
    })

    err = peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(answer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    answerBytes, _ := json.Marshal(answer)

    gatheringComplete := webrtc.GatheringCompletePromise(peerConnection)
    <-gatheringComplete

    err = setSDP(signalServerURL, "person2", answerBytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    peerConnection.OnDataChannel(func(dc *webrtc.DataChannel) {
        fmt.Printf("Data channel '%s'-'%d' opened by offerer\n", dc.Label(), dc.ID())

        // Handle when the data channel is open
        dc.OnOpen(func() {
            fmt.Println("Data channel is open on answerer side")

            // Start reading from CLI and sending via data channel
            go func() {
                reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
                for {
                    fmt.Print("Enter message (Answerer): ")
                    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
                    text = strings.TrimSpace(text)

                    if text == "exit" {
                        fmt.Println("Exiting...")
                        os.Exit(0)
                    }

                    // Send the message via the data channel
                    err := dc.SendText(text)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal("Error sending text message from answerer:", err)
                    }
                }
            }()
        })

        dc.OnMessage(func(msg webrtc.DataChannelMessage) {
            fmt.Printf("Message from offerer: %s\n", string(msg.Data))
        })

    })

    select {}
}


singalling_server.go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3"
)

var mp map[string]interface{}

type sdpDetails struct {
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    SdpInfoStr string `json:"sdp"`
}

func signallingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    name := vars["name"]
    if value, ok := mp[name]; ok {
        valueInBytes, _ := json.Marshal(value)
        _, err := w.Write(valueInBytes)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        return
    }
    notFoundResp := fmt.Sprintf("No sdp info exists for name %s", name)
    w.Write([]byte(notFoundResp))
}

func addSDPHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    var sdpInfo sdpDetails
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &sdpInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if mp == nil {
        mp = make(map[string]interface{})
    }
    var remoteSDP webrtc.SessionDescription
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(sdpInfo.SdpInfoStr), &remoteSDP)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // fmt.Println("name", sdpInfo.Name, "sdpInfo", remoteSDP)
    mp[sdpInfo.Name] = remoteSDP
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/signal/{name}", signallingHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/signal", addSDPHandler).Methods("POST")

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9099", r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}



Hey guys, would really appreciate any help I can get with this. TIA!
